# renaming user file back after I accidentally set it as a file for videos

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles, user-folders

I was changing the locations of some files such as (Desktop, Downloads, Videos) from main disk *C:/* to my second disk *D:/* , due to lack of space, I have accidentally change **user file** to the main folder for **videos**. I am trying to set the **location** of a Video folder to his **default** location. However, going to folder properties and trying to change it back does not work I get **access denied** message. I tried to change location in Regedit, This will work if I take a Print screen it will be saved there. But name of the User remains the same.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In **Explorer**, open the folder that is displaying the wrong name.
2. Shift+right-click in the background & select **Open PowerShell window here**.
3. Verify the path in the prompt is displaying the correct folder name.
4. Cpoy & paste this command: `ri desktop.ini -force`.
5. Sign out & back in.

Comment: thank you !! it worked.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the feedback.